# Confusing Offset in my Support Vector Regression and other Models

Tags: regression, svm, prediction

I am experiencing a weird offset in my Support Vector Regression prediction (code below).

A brief overview: I have a set of 10 .xls sheets as input data (each with 30 rows and 27 columns), and a 11th .xls sheet that I am using as my testing dataset.

I am working with an electricity dataset, and I am trying to predict the 11th month of electricity usage using the SVR.  I am using the code written and released by Luke Benning on Github: https://github.com/lbenning/Load-Forecasting

All of my datasets are structured the same, but when I run the prediction model, I am receiving an offset (as shown in the photo below).  The actual data versus the predicted data seem to follow a similar pattern, but the two plots are offset.

Does anyone know of what I may want to explore in order to try and understand the source of this offset?

[image]

```
#! /usr/bin/python

import math
import statistics
import visualizer
import numpy as np
from datagen import constructData
from sklearn import svm

# Applies Support Vector Regression to the electricity dataset,
# prints out the accuracy rate to the terminal and plots
# predictions against actual values
def suppVectorRegress():

    kernelList = ["linear","rbf",polyKernel]
    names = ["linear","radial basis","poly"]
    preds = []

    # Retrieve time series data & apply preprocessing
    data = constructData()

    cutoff = len(data)-30
    xTrain = data[0][0:cutoff]
    yTrain = data[1][0:cutoff]
    xTest = data[0][cutoff:]
    yTest = data[1][cutoff:]

    # Fill in missing values denoted by zeroes as an average of
    # both neighbors
    statistics.estimateMissing(xTrain,0.0)
    statistics.estimateMissing(xTest,0.0)

    # Logarithmically scale the data
    xTrain = [[math.log(y) for y in x] for x in xTrain]
    xTest = [[math.log(y) for y in x] for x in xTest]
    yTrain = [math.log(x) for x in yTrain]

    # Detrend the time series
    indices = np.arange(len(data[1]))
    trainIndices = indices[0:cutoff]
    testIndices = indices[cutoff:]
    detrended,slope,intercept = statistics.detrend(trainIndices,yTrain)
    yTrain = detrended

    for gen in range(len(kernelList)):

        # Use SVR to predict test observations based upon training observations
        pred = svrPredictions(xTrain,yTrain,xTest,kernelList[gen])
        # Add the trend back into the predictions
        trendedPred = statistics.reapplyTrend(testIndices,pred,slope,intercept)
        # Reverse the normalization
        trendedPred = [math.exp(x) for x in trendedPred]
        # Compute the NRMSE
        err = statistics.normRmse(yTest,trendedPred)

        print ("The Normalized Root-Mean Square Error is " + str(err) + " using kernel " + names[gen] + "...")

        preds.append(trendedPred)

    names.append("actual")
    preds.append(yTest)

    # Change the parameters 2017,2,1 based on the month you want to predict.
    visualizer.comparisonPlot(2017,2,1,preds,names,plotName="Support Vector Regression Load Predictions vs. Actual", 
        yAxisName="Predicted Kilowatts")

# Construct a support vector machine and get predictions
# for the test set
# Returns a 1-d vector of predictions
def svrPredictions(xTrain,yTrain,xTest,k):
    clf = svm.SVR(C=2.0,kernel=k)
    clf.fit(xTrain,yTrain)
    return clf.predict(xTest)

# A scale invariant kernel (note only conditionally semi-definite)
def polyKernel(x,y):
    return (np.dot(x,y.T)+1.0)**0.95

if __name__=="__main__":
    suppVectorRegress()
```

I am generating the data as follows:

```
'''
Functions for retrieving Elia dataset 
& forming training/testing datasets
'''

# constructs dataset for simulations
# the last dataset in this file list, is the one used as the training set.
def constructData():
  files = ["data/jan_16_elec_scaled.xls", "data/feb_16_elec_scaled.xls", 
           "data/mar_16_elec_scaled.xls", "data/apr_16_elec_scaled.xls",
           "data/may_16_elec_scaled.xls","data/jun_16_elec_scaled.xls",
           "data/jul_16_elec_scaled.xls", "data/aug_16_elec_scaled.xls",
           "data/sep_16_elec_scaled.xls", "data/oct_16_elec_scaled.xls",
           "data/nov_16_elec_scaled.xls"]

#  files = ["data/jan_16_elec_NOscaled.xls", "data/feb_16_elec_NOscaled.xls", 
#           "data/mar_16_elec_NOscaled.xls", "data/apr_16_elec_NOscaled.xls",
#           "data/may_16_elec_NOscaled.xls","data/jun_16_elec_NOscaled.xls",
#           "data/jul_16_elec_NOscaled.xls", "data/aug_16_elec_NOscaled.xls",
#           "data/sep_16_elec_NOscaled.xls", "data/oct_16_elec_NOscaled.xls",
#           "data/nov_16_elec_NOscaled.xls"]         
  return labelSeries(loadSeries(files))

# constructs labelled data from a
# univariate time series
sdef labelSeries(series):
  xData = []
  yData = []
  for x in range(len(series)-1):
    xData.append(series[x]) # xData contains all of the items up until the last item
    yData.append(np.mean(series[x+1])) # yData is the last item in the list
  return (xData,yData)

# arg1 : list of excel spreadsheets filenames
# returns : load univariate time series
def loadSeries(fileList):
  # Retrieve time series examples
  xData = []
  for fileName in fileList:
    book = xlrd.open_workbook(fileName)
    sheet = book.sheet_by_index(0)
    for rx in range(2,sheet.nrows):
      row = sheet.row(rx)[3:]
      row = [row[x].value for x in range(0,len(row)-4)]
      xData.append(row)
  return xData
```

Answer (score 1):

See this [answer](http://www.alivelearn.net/?p=1666) by Xu Cui. The reason, as he stated is simple: the model itself is very simple SVM. He suggests lagging 2 points behind to "improve" and get a more powerful model. Let me know what you think of it. We might be overthinking and he might be on point.

Comment: Based on my code given, do you know how to add this lag?

Comment: Hi @Gary I am not sure whether your data is an matrix or a list. Assuming it is a matrix with the topmost row as the oldest observation then xTrain should be xTrain = xTrain[ 0:-2 , :] , and yTrain[2:,]. the svm can be kept as is. just adjust the training data such that you are calculating Yt in terms of Xt-2. hope this helps.